# R script to add multiple Y series on the same axis X

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new into R and I've tried to complete the chart below using ggplot2. It sounds trivial but it is quite difficult to achieve, at least at my level.

[Chart[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwABm.png)

Here is the dataframe :

```
datasum.tpv = data.frame(Quarters = factor(c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4")), 
                         Toronto = c(282.39, 79.48, 128.24, 123.70) , 
                         Paris = c(153.17, 150.11, 26.41, 68.50), 
                         Vancouver = c(315.70, 103.36, 97.02, 377.70))
```

I've tried this script but it piles data on top of each others despite using the position dodge function...

```
final.structure.tpv = ggplot(data=datasum.tpv, aes(x=Quarters))+
      geom_col(aes(y = Toronto, colour = "Toronto"), position = "dodge")+ 
      geom_col(aes(y = Paris, colour = "Paris"), position = "dodge")+
      geom_col(aes(y = Vancouver, colour = "Vancouver"), position = "dodge")
```

Any help is welcome,
Thanks

Comment: Put your data in "long" format and this will be much easier. For example: `library(tidyverse);
ggplot(gather(datasum.tpv, City, Value, -Quarters), aes(Quarters, Value, fill=City)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(0.75), width=0.7)`

Comment: Hi eipi! Works well, thanks! i guess I needed the additional packages tidyr to make it work. Good to know. See ya!

Comment: Well, you don't *need* to use `tidyr`. The key idea is making your data long rather than wide. `tidyr` just makes it easy to do that, but there are other ways to get the same result using base R, the `reshape2` pacakge, or the `data.table` package.

Answer (score 0):

This works, just sub out "Value" in the two places with whatever you need. Whenever you are using ggplot convert to long format. Whenever you are converting to long format use `gather` ;)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

datasum.tpv = data.frame(Quarters = factor(c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4")), 
                         Toronto = c(282.39, 79.48, 128.24, 123.70) , 
                         Paris = c(153.17, 150.11, 26.41, 68.50), 
                         Vancouver = c(315.70, 103.36, 97.02, 377.70))

datasum.tpv %>% 
  gather(City, Value, 2:4) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Quarters, y = Value, fill = City)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

Comment: `ggplot` always puts the fill items in alphabetical order (Paris, Toronto, Vancouver). If you want a custom ordering you can reorder the factor levels like this: `mutate(City = factor(City, levels = c("Toronto", "Paris", "Vancouver")`

Comment: (which will go after the `gather` line)